# TTGO TS I²C adress

Tags: i2c, wifi, esp32, wire-library, espressif

I'm working on a project using TTGO TS wich communicate wih arduino via I²C protocole
How can I find the adress of TTGO TS board used in I²C communication ?

Comment: you would find out the address by reading the instruction manual, or the datasheet

Comment: You could also use an I2C scanner (google it, there are dozens of them out there).

Answer (score 1):

The TTGO TS uses an ST7735 display. This is *not* an I2C device. Instead it uses its own custom serial protocol. Since the DC pin is broken out for you it uses the 4-wire serial interface which is simplest to use with SPI.

It's confusing that they use the terms SCL and SDA, which makes you think it's I2C, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Like @romkey said, use a I²C scanner to find the address of the device, for example [this](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner/) one from the Arduino website. Connect the device to the Arduino board, upload the code and look up the I²C address of your device.